# Mismatch while comparing a c-style character array using strcmp()

Tags: c++

I'm new learner of c++. I'm working on string comparison. But it give me wrong answer while I'm comparing correct string given in below code:

```
char string[100] = {"a"};
if (strcmp(string,"a")){
     cout<<"Matched";
}else{
     cout<<"Not Matched";
}
```

Output:

> Not Matched

Please hep me to solve this.

Comment: If you are using C++, please use `std::string`.

Comment: I strongly urge you to compile with all warnings enables, and fix them!

Comment: `if (strcmp(string,"a") == 0) {cout<<"Matched";} else {...}` (that's after fixing `char string[100] = "a";`)

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char str[100] = "a";

    if (0 == strcmp(str,"a")){
        std::cout << "Matched" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not Matched" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

because, as the [standard](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) says, the contents of both strings passed to the `strcmp` function are equal if the return value is 0.

However, if you use C++, then I strongly suggest you using `std::string` instead char array.

Comment: You need to either add `'\n'` at the end of each current `std::cout` or just an additional `std::cout << '\n';` after the conditional to make the code POSIX compliant (that way it doesn't mess up my prompt)

Comment: Thanks. I will add that. Totally forgot about it.

Comment: That works too!, though I was thinking just `"Matched\n"`, etc.. would be fine `:)`

Comment: `char str[100] = {"a"}` is still incorrect.   It would be more correct as `char str[100] = "a"`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), strcmp does not return a boolean.

You want

```
if (strcmp(string,"a") == 0){
```

Comment: Might want to comment on the superfluous `{ .. }` in `char string[100] = {"a"};`

Answer (score 1):

Given the other answers, I would like to provide the solution in C++ instead of using the archaic C constructions.

In C++, we try to avoid C arrays (`type name[count]`) and instead use `std::vector<type>` and `std::array<type, count>`. Especially for strings, using arrays doesn't make sense, as we have `std::string` and `std::string_view`. The first contains ownership of the data, the second does not. Both of them are intuitive in usage, as simple comparison `==` returns true or false, while the `strcmp` function returns a tristate, where 0 (implicitly converted to false) means they are equal.

So, in practice, the code will look like this.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::string string = "a";
    if (string == "a")
        std::cout << "Matched";
    else
        std::cout << "Not Matched";
}
```

[Code at compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/6HlLMT)

Comment: A little nitty nitpick: One should avoid using variable names the same as type names like `std::string string = "a";`, correct namespace usage or not.

Comment: Agreed, however, I did not want to rename variables to allow matching with the original code

Comment: Well, at least if it's not flagged as irrelevant, we have documented that aspect in the comments here :)